# ADO.NET stored procedure for inserting not working

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a database which stores information about a library (books, authors & categories).

But I can't get my stored procedure to work for inserting data. The stored procedure itself executes fine, but when I perform a test, it simply doesn't add anything to the database. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

This is my stored procedure (for category):

```
USE MyLibrary
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'CategoryInsert' AND TYPE = 'P')
BEGIN
    DROP PROC CategoryInsert
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CategoryInsert
(
    @Id int out,
    @Name nvarchar(255),
    @InsertedBy nvarchar(120),
    @InsertedOn datetime
)
AS
DECLARE @CurrentId int
SELECT @CurrentId = Id FROM Category WHERE lower(@Name) = lower(@Name)
IF @CurrentId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Id = -100
    RETURN
END
INSERT INTO Category
(
    Name,
    InsertedBy,
    InsertedOn
)
VALUES
(
    @Name,
    @InsertedBy,
    @InsertedOn
)
SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
GO
```

This is my test:

```
USE MyLibrary
GO

DECLARE @NewId int
DECLARE @date datetime
SET @date = getdate()

EXEC CategoryInsert @NewId, 'Testing', 'AL', @date

SELECT @NewId
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
SELECT @CurrentId = Id FROM Category WHERE lower(@Name) = lower(@Name)
IF @CurrentId IS NOT NULL
```

The equality check will always return true because you're essentially comparing `WHERE 1 = 1`, which means that `@CurrentID` will always have a value and thus your stored procedure will always return before the `INSERT` happens.